# Turning on mousekeys when numlock is turned off

Tags: windows-10

I use the numpad for entering numbers almost exclusively. However, I also use Windows Mousekeys often. Is there any way to configure my system in a way, so the numpad inputs numbers when NUMLOCK is ON, and works as Mousekeys when NUMLOCK is OFF?

Comment: Windows already implemented this. Look around in the Mouse Keys settings and you'll find it.

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking at the mousekeys settings in Windows Tablet-like menu, not the mousekeys settings in the control panel.

Comment: It's pretty confusing right now. Microsoft haven't moved everything to the new Settings app yet.